# Calculating probability of $~p~$ from binary entropy using logarithm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logarithms, information-theory, entropy

A person roll a dice using a dice that is not fair The result of dice rolling is reported in even odd
 and large / medium / small ("Small" mean $\{1,2\}$ , medium means $\{3,4\}$ , large means $\{5,6\}$)

$X$ represent probability distribution
 where $Pr~\{\text{even, odd}\}$ and $~Y~$ represent probability distribution $Pr ~\{S,M,L\}$

It is known that the probability
 that the fourth eye of this dice appears and the odd probability are equal, and further that the entropy of the random variable $~X~$ is $~H (X) =0.97095~$ bits. 
 Find the probability of getting $~4~$ eyes ($Pr~ \{X=\text{odd}\}$)

$$H(X)=0.97095= - ~p ~\ln p - (1-p)~\ln(1-p)$$
I need to find $~p~$.

The answer is $~0.6~$ and $~0.4~$, 
but how can I find it when the logarithm is in base $~2~$?
and also how can I find $~p~$ with just only this information and using logarithm property ?

$$\ln 0.97095=\ln \frac{1}{p^p}~ \frac {1}{(1-p)^{1-p}}~?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like reading a graph, the below graph relates binary entropy with probability.  From this graph, it is clear that p = 0.4 and (1-p) = 0.6 for which H = 0.97095.  Algebraically it is difficult to find out.

Good luck[image]

Comment: yes you right thanks so much!! but why i  need to use binary entropy for this? i edit my question this actually try to find probability for odd-even dice, i mean i can use binary entropy whenever probability is binary(?) like even-odd, head-tail?

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Binary entropy relates to the case of binary out comes and for $H(X)= - ~p ~\ln p - (1-p)~\ln(1-p)$.  For trinary $$H(X)= - ~p_1 ~\ln p_1 - ~p_2 ~\ln p_2-(1-p_1-p_2)~\ln(1-p_1-p_2)$$. You can create a surface for different value of $p_1, p_2, p_3$ in the case of trinary outcomes.